# How to convert a JavaScript array of doubles to a .NET array of doubles?

Tags: c#, .net, javascript, browser

What is the best way to convert a JavaScript array of doubles

```
return [2.145, 1.111, 7.893];
```

into a .NET array of doubles, when the Javascript array is returned from a webbrowser controls document object

```
object o = Document.InvokeScript("getMapPanelRegion");
```

without using strings and parsing?

The object returned is of type __ComObject as it is an array being returned. The array will be a fixed size as I am using this to return three values back to the calling code. My current solution is to return a | deliminated string of the three value, I then split and parse the string to get my three doubles. If possible I would like to not have to use the string manipulation as this feels like a hack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [MSDN (HtmlDocument.InvokeScript Method)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4b1a88bz(VS.80).aspx):

> The underlying type of the object returned by InvokeScript will vary. If the called Active Scripting function returns scalar data, such as a **string** or an **integer**, it will be returned as a **string** ...

It seems that integers will be returned as string, you could asume that the same applies to doubles.

**EDIT:**
I forgot that you were talking about an array. Anyhow, MSDN continues:

> ... If it returns a script-based object, such as an object created **using JScript or VBScript's new operator**, it will be of type **Object** ...

So it seems that you will get an object instead, but that doesn't help the fact that you will have to convert it inside your C# code.

**EDIT 2:**

As for the conversion of the actual ComObject. After reading [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/arraysvbatocssv1.aspx?fid=247508&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3&sort=Position&view=Quick&select=3090996&fr=1) which is about Excel, but it still returns a ComObject, it seems that your current aproach with the string seems like the simpler one. Sometimes a hack is the best solution :D

Comment: But I have an array of doubles and they are treated differently.

Comment: The problem is getting the __ComObject into my .NET array.

Comment: I agree that a hack is sometimes the best solution, but I'll feel better about it once I've explored as many possibilities as I can.

Answer (score 0):

This "problem" amounts to transforming VARIANT into an C# array. For this probably the easiest way is to use reflection. Here is how:

```
private static IEnumerable<object> SafeArrayToEnmrble (object comObject)
{
    Type comObjectType = comObject.GetType();
    // spot here what is the type required
    if (comObjectType != typeof(object[,]))
    // return empty array, throw exception or whatever is your fancy
        return new object[0];

    int count = (int)comObjectType.InvokeMember("Length", BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, comObject, null);
    var result = new List<object>(count);

    var indexArgs = new object[2];
    for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++)
    {
        indexArgs[0] = i;
        indexArgs[1] = 1;
        object valueAtIndex = comObjectType.InvokeMember("GetValue", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, comObject, indexArgs);
        result.Add(valueAtIndex);
    }

    return result;
}
```